# Hilbert classification

Tags: functions

I saw beautiful movie "The Story of Maths" of Marcus du Sautoy. In 3-rd part "To Infinity and Beyond" it was mentioned about Hilbert classification. It was mentioned that "Hilbert showed that, while there were аn infinity оf equations, these equations cоuld be constructed frоm а finite number оf building block lіke sets." This words are curious for me. But i can not find more about that in web. Could you please give me reference where i can read about the classification in more detail but in popular style? I am not professional mathematician. I am physicist :) The topic is very interesting!

Comment: Are you interested in the logic that allows one to deduce this or what exactly are you curious about?

Comment: i am curious about these words: "equations cоuld be constructed frоm а finite number оf building block lіke sets". The logic of deduce is not interesting while. Formulation of this classification is interesting.

Comment: I think they are referring to the Hilbert basis theorem.